# Presenting a UIVIew from a container view modally (nav bar missing)

Tags: iphone, view, navigation, containers

I am a bit new to iPhone development and working on learning it on my own.

I have a view controller which contains 2 parts:

1. Image View - some picture + some text on top of it
2. Container view

the container view is now segued into a new controller view which I replaced with a collection view. The idea here is for this to hold some picture I can click on to get to another page yet.

So, with all that, I have things working fine. My main view shows the top picture + text and below is all the smaller pictures which are clickable and that take me to another view that is being presented modally.

The final view is a UIView that contains in it a imageView to hold the picture I clicked on the other view. This even works fine.

The issue is that I am trying to add a naviagtion bar on top of the new view which shows up fine in story board and I added a button to close it. But that for some reason does not show up when I run the application.

If I change the presenting mode to Push, I see the navigation bar show up with the back button as well, but my close button does not work there either (code added to dismiss the view correctly).

What am I doing wrong with the modal presentation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to present a view with a navbar modally, it has to have it own `NavigationController`.
So too have a NavigationBar in a modal displayed View, drag a `UINavigationViewController` in front of your ViewController, e.g.:

[image: Modally connected NavigationViewController]

This is not needed in case of a `push` segue, as the pushed ViewController is still child of the original `UINavigationViewController`, wich is owner of the `NavigationBar`
 The NavigationBar is managed by the `UINavigationController`, wich is on the parent-side.
So if you add Buttons in the Storyboard, you are adding these buttons to the `NavigationItem`, wich belongs to the ViewController.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried that before I posted the quetion and it does not seem to work either. I am not sure if this is specific to only container views. I am pretty sure this works fine in the case you show above where it is a Master view controller and the Nav Controller follower by some other controller as I tried that in another experiment just to make sure.  My issue seems to be most related to the container view I had. Let me see if I can take a picture of my story board to show the flow better and see what might be the issue with my design